# consulta sobre Macros de Excel

Tags: excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opxtc.png)Buenos Días,

Durante estos días, he estado aprendiendo a crear Macros de Excel a través de tutoriales de YouTube.

Siguiendo las indicaciones de los tutoriales, he conseguido crearlas correctamente y han funcionado. Pero por motivos que desconozco, al cabo de un par de días han dejado de funcionar.

Los mensajes que me aparecen os los envío en las imágenes adjuntas

¿sabrías indicarme qué puedo hacer para que todo se normalice?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías ponernos el código que provoca el error, de otra forma no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: el mensaje que me aparece es : se ha producido el error 438 en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: mi PC es Windows 10

Comment: ¿Cómo has hecho  la macro? ¿Con Grabar Macro? Si es así, tienes que ir al código (Alt+F11) o borón "Visual Basic". Allí tienes que buscar tu macro en la parte de la izquierda, seleccionarla y presionar F5 para ver donde se produce ele error. Pero copias el código, editas la pregunta y lo pegas ahí para que lo podamos evaluar.

Comment: Te he hecho un copia pega de lo que me sale. Espero que te sirva
Lo tienes en la parte superior de esta consulta

Comment: Prueba con `ActiveSheet.Selection.OnAction = "Macro1"`

Comment: Aunque realmente, no se exactamente que tiene que hacer. Si eliminas la línea `Selection.OnAction= "Macro1"` ¿Sigue el error? ¿La Macro hace lo que tu quieres?

Comment: Parece que cuando elimino ActiveSheet.Selection.OnAction = "Macro1" se soluciona este problema. Pero cuando le solicito varias veces algún dato filtrado, desaparecen todos los datos de todas las celdas de la hoja

Answer (score 0):

El problema real está en la línea `Selection.OnAction = "Macro1"`. Esta línea lanza el error puesto que no se le puede asignar el "OnAction" a una celda (ni a un rango).

Para suplir esto, una opción es crear un botón que lance esta acción

```
Dim button As Object
Set button = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(350, 10, 200, 25)
button.OnAction = "Macro1"
```

Estas tres línea sustituyen a la línea `Selection.OnAction = "Macro1"`
Con esto tendríamos la misma funcionalidad anterior pero sin el error.

Comment: OK.

Gracias y así lo hago